# Which Visa for Indian citizen in US travelling to Dubai en-route to India?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, dubai, uae

I am an Indian citizen living in the US. I am travelling to India this November to India. I am going to stop in Dubai for visiting my friend. I am confused regarding which visa to take as I would also be travelling from DXB to DWC

**Onward from US to India**

US to DWC - Reaching DWC on 27 Nov

DXB to India - 30 Nov

**Return from India to US**

India to DXB - 03 Jan

DWC to US - 03 Jan

My question is If I take 30 days short term visa starting on 27 Nov, it will expire on 27 Dec. Then do I need visa for travelling ( through metro or shuttle or taxi ) from DXB to DWC? If yes, which one should I take? Please help me.

Comment: Which airline are you flying from the US that is landing in DWC?

Comment: It is Qatar Airways

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a visa for both itineraries.

On your return flight, you need a transit visa.
On your inbound flight, you'll need a normal short stay visa.